# Why won't my board appear? Creating a game in java

Tags: java, swing

First off I would like to say that I understand I am asking a lot so any help would be appreciated and I thank you for your time. I am extremely grateful.

Anyway I am creating a game for my A2 coursework, most commonly known as Checkers. I have completed my code and everything works as I had planned except that the CheckerBoard itself as well as the checkerpieces do not appear to be showing.

The section of were my board should be present is just a black space. Although my board does not appear to be displaying, all of the actions I perform on it such as clicking certain section produces the planned response, and although I've checked through my code I cannot work out what I've done wrong.

Anyway if anyone could possibly spot my mistake or perhaps give me some advice I would be extremely grateful. Thank you

As I of course can't upload my entire code I will do snippets of where I think the problem might lie or just important sections. Thank you

```
CheckerBoard content = new CheckerBoard(); // Sets the CheckerBoard values into the content to be used in the next line
        application.setContentPane(content); // Container holds the values together, Content pane of the CheckerBoard
        application.pack();  // Use preferred size of content to set size of application.
        Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        application.setLocation( (screensize.width - application.getWidth())/2,
                (screensize.height - application.getHeight())/2 );
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); // Sets so that the application can be exited when the application is closed
        application.setResizable(false);  // This makes it so that the user can't change the application's size.
        application.setVisible(true); // Sets it so that the application can actually be seen
```

The code above is placed within a "public static void main(String[] args)"

Then below that I have:

```
public CheckerBoard()  {
// This is going to be a constructor, this constructor will set the layout manager for the panel to be null, it will then add components to the panel
// and it will set their bounds.

    setLayout(null);  // So that it will match my requirement specification, I will do the layout myself
    setBackground(new Color(0,120,0));  // Dark Green Background colour.
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,250)); // The size of the Panel

    BoardComplete checkerboardData = new BoardComplete();
    add(checkerboardData); // This will create the components and add them to the content pane
    add(NewGameButton);
    add(ResignButton);
    add(MessageDisplay);

 // I will now have to produce a method to set the position and size of each component by calling its setBounds() method
    checkerboardData.setBounds(20,20,164,164); // Sets the board dimensions
    NewGameButton.setBounds(210, 60, 120, 30); 
    ResignButton.setBounds(210, 120, 120, 30); 
    MessageDisplay.setBounds(20, 200, 350, 30); 
    }
```

And then finally I have a another public class called BoardComplete which contains all the relevant code involving the actionlistners ect. used:

```
 BoardComplete() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addMouseListener(this);
        ResignButton = new JButton("Resign");
        ResignButton.addActionListener(this);
        NewGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        NewGameButton.addActionListener(this);
        MessageDisplay = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);
        MessageDisplay.setFont(new  Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        MessageDisplay.setForeground(Color.green);
        checkerboardData = new DataForCheckers();
        MakeaNewGame();
    }
```

I understand that this is a lot to ask but any help would be greatly appreciate and I would be extremely grateful. Thank you.

Edit due to comment: This is the code for my Paint Class:

```
    public void PaintCheckerBoard(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // This will draw a two-pixel black border around the edges of the canvas. 

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0,0,getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);
        g.drawRect(1,1,getSize().width-3,getSize().height-3);

        // Draw the squares of the checkerboard and the checkers.

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                if ( row % 2 == col % 2 )
                    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(2 + col*20, 2 + row*20, 20, 20);
                switch (checkerboardData.PieceLocation(row,col)) {
                case DataForCheckers.RED:
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    break;
                case DataForCheckers.BLACK:
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    break;
                case DataForCheckers.RED_KING:
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("K", 7 + col*20, 16 + row*20);
                    break;
                case DataForCheckers.BLACK_KING:
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("K", 7 + col*20, 16 + row*20);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // If there is a game in progress, highlight the legal moves that the player can make.
        // It can be seen that in this process, LegalMoves is never null while a game is in progress     

        if (CheckerMatchInProgress) {
            /* First, draw a 2-pixel cyan border around the pieces that can be moved. */
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            for (int i = 0; i < LegalMoves.length; i++) {
                g.drawRect(2 + LegalMoves[i].fromCol*20, 2 + LegalMoves[i].fromRow*20, 19, 19);
                g.drawRect(3 + LegalMoves[i].fromCol*20, 3 + LegalMoves[i].fromRow*20, 17, 17);
            }
            // If a piece is selected to be moved, for example if ChosenRow>=0, then
            // draw a 2-pixel white border around that piece, and draw a green border
            // around each square that the piece can be legally moved to.

            if (ChosenRow >= 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.drawRect(2 + ChosenColumn*20, 2 + ChosenRow*20, 19, 19);
                g.drawRect(3 + ChosenColumn*20, 3 + ChosenRow*20, 17, 17);
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                for (int i = 0; i < LegalMoves.length; i++) {
                    if (LegalMoves[i].fromCol == ChosenColumn && LegalMoves[i].fromRow == ChosenRow) {
                        g.drawRect(2 + LegalMoves[i].toCol*20, 2 + LegalMoves[i].toRow*20, 19, 19);
                        g.drawRect(3 + LegalMoves[i].toCol*20, 3 + LegalMoves[i].toRow*20, 17, 17);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }  // end PaintCheckerBoard()
```

Comment: so are your buttons showing up? have you tried adding some random visual object to the content pane, does that appear? Have you modified the order in which items are added to the content pane?

Comment: does calling revalidate() at the end of the CheckerBoard() constructor help? (after you call setBounds on your buttons and checkerboardData)

Comment: @hexobolic  The buttons do show up, everything apart from the checkerboard and the checkerpieces appear, the checkerboard is just a black space, what I have noticed is that within the BoardComplete(), if you change the setBackground(Color.BLACK) to white, it will change the colour of the section to white, but the checkboard is still unshowing if that is anyhelp as maybe  the problem might lie there? Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Subler Thank you for your answer, I tried that but it didn't change anything sadly,  I have noticed is that within the BoardComplete(), if you change the setBackground(Color.BLACK) to WHITE, it will change the colour of the section to white, but the checkboard is still unshowing if that is anyhelp as maybe the problem might lie there? anyway I am grateful for your answer and thank you for your time :)

Comment: So the only problem is showing the actual playing-pieces and checkers style background, but there doesnt seem to be any code in the snippets youve provided that have anything to do with this? I'm assuming you'd do this by overriding paintComponent on your BoardComplete class. Could you post the code thats actually supposed to draw the board and pieces?

Comment: @Subler   I have inputted the relevant code that you've mention back into the question, I have included all of the paintComponent class, it is at the bottom section of the question now, so hopefully this will provide you with a more complete understanding

On a side note I would just like to say that I appreciate your responses and am extremely grateful fo

Comment: ok you dont happen to call super.paintComponent(g) AFTER calling this paint method u've just added do u?

Comment: In Swing all GUI operations should be done in the Swing thread, not on your threads. If you don't do it like this, you will have random bugs. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: @Subler    The paint method that I've shown in the code above is the only paint method that I have within my code

Comment: so you don't override the paintComponent method? so then where do u call this paint method from?

Comment: @Subler  I did it myself, I have to make my game suit a specification and so I set the layout to null and designed the layout myself, I can upload more relevant code if that would help understanding?

Comment: i still dont know where you call this method from then, but try overriding the paintComponent method like this: public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g); PaintCheckerBoard(g); } . and then keep in mind to call the repaint() method anytime something on your checkersboard changes (a piece has been moved).

Comment: @Subler I am extremely grateful for your help and thank you for your time, I can't express that enough :)
I will try and use your advice although it confuses me slightly haha, I was wondering, if you would prefer a further understanding and possibly help me further, I have uploaded the full class of code to [link](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/43951-checkerboard-wont-appear-creating-game-java.html#post174192) If you could possibly take I look I would be extremely grateful, however if not I am still extremely grateful and I thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking through your code on the other site, your custom paint method never seems to be getting called from anywhere. You're supposed to override the paintComponent method from the Component class (JPanel is a subclass of Component). This paintComponent method will be called whenever swing thinks, or is told to redraw something.

So, add this code to your BoardComplete class:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    PaintCheckerBoard(g);
}
```

super.paintComponent will do anything swing would do to paint this component (which at this point is just drawing the background). And then you pass the Graphics object to your own custom paint method, that method will draw your entire game on the Graphics object, and swing will display whatever is drawn on there for you.

So now you have to remember also to call repaint() every time something in your game changes. The repaint() method will just tell swing he should repaint something (note: this tells the awt thread it should repaint the component, so it happens asynchronously from where youre calling repaint()).

If youre still confused, you should probably look up some information or tutorials on how to draw with awt/swing using this method.

Comment: Yes that has fixed it, thank you so much, honestly I am so grateful, I am really thankful for your help and time given, I can't state that enough. That problem has had me stuck for days, Thank you so much :)